# Why Mac Os is better than windows or linux for development of web applications?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

I could understand why its better than windows in some ways but other than UI what is stand different than Linux ??

Comment: I don't think it is better. That is just your opinion, and I disagree with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to ask me, or anyone else in my rather web-heavy circle of friends, Mac OS is hardly better for anything, and very expensive to boot. I think whoever told you Mac OS is better was quite misinformed, as I would say that the three are probably balanced in their capacity to support web designers.

A few possible points a MacOS supporter might make:

- MacOS is "more stable" or "better supported." (I find this questionable, but it isn't unreasonable)
- MacOS offers the UNIX features of Linux combined with the "professionality" of Windows.
- A Mac generally comes with fairly powerful hardware, which is important for any development machine, and might make an observer think is OS is the good part.

However, I remain a die-hard Linux junkie. MacOS probably isn't any better for web dev than any machine running any other OS. The power of the computer is in what you do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. (see below)

Ideally, a developer should within a local environment that is as close as possible to what he/she expects to see in their production environment.

If your production servers run on a Unix system, it will be easier and arguably better to work on a Unix-based computer. Most of the time you will run in to fewer deployment issues.
For this reason (aside from personal ones), a lot of web developers use MacOs, since it has a unix terminal.

In other words, **it depends on your environment/deployment goals**. I personally prefer Windows 10, but I am comfortable in either. And, in my opinion, a developer should never swear allegiance to a brand/technology/platform, as these are temporary and constantly changing.
Avoid fanboy mentality.